# Binary Search small error Python 3.5

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, binary-search

I'm creating a Binary Search for class.

It should display `True` or `False` depending if the value is within the list.

I cant get the last element without errors, my code so far:

```
def binarySearch(alist, value):
    first = 0                               
    last = len(alist)-1                                                  
    found = False                           

    while first <= last and not found:                    
        midpoint = (first + last)//2        
        print(midpoint)                     
        if value == midpoint:
            found = True
        else:
            if value < alist[midpoint]:
                last = midpoint-1
            else:
                first = midpoint+1

    return found


print(binarySearch([1,2,3,4,5],5))
```

The line: `last = len(alist)-1` does not recognize the last element within a list? It goes to the one before last, so, if I ran the code above it would return `False` when it should return `True`.

I tried `last = len(alist)` which gives me the last element however if I try searching for a number higher than `5` it causes an `IndexError` rather than displaying `False`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `len(alist)` returns length of list. if you want last element of list you should use `alist[len(alist) -1]`

Comment: Quick note, last = len(alist)%10 works for last element everytime.

Comment: I also changed the while loop condition to,  '''while first < last and not found'''    rather than' first <= last'. which seems to get rid of both errors :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking the value against the index `midpoint` and not the values in the array.

```
if value == midpoint:
```

Should instead be:

```
if value == alist[midpoint]:
```